# Vue.js with cometd

Tags: vue.js, cometd

Has anyone tried implementing vue.js with cometd? Do we have to use jquery version of cometd or is there any specific cometd version for vue.js like angular.js?

Comment: There is no binding for VueJS in cometd as far as I know. But cometd core library is vanilla javascript, and Vue is not as opinionated as Angular is. You should be able to easily use them together.

Comment: Thank you. Will go with jQuery / Vanilla JS. I was wondering if anybody have used it and what approach did they follow. Thanks again.